# Select an item in an IE combobox

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I've got the correct code to navigate to a website where I want to start populating the dropdown lists and fields etc. The code I've been trying, following @Bond 's suggestion, is:

```
Sub GetQuote()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.navigate ("website")

IE.Visible = True

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

Dim e
Set e = IE.document.getElementsByClassname("id of button")(1)
e.Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

Dim z As Object

Set z = IE.document.getElementbyid("vehicleYearOfManufactureList")
z.SelectedIndex = 4

End Sub
```

This used to populate the first dropdown with the value 2012 but now I just get a run-time error where object is required. Could it be because previously the link that is clicked on used to open in the same and current window, and now it's somehow opening an entirely new window? I'm just baffled by how the same code works and then doesn't work, assuming no changes have been made to the source code it references.

The line that is highlighted in the debug of this error is: Set z = IE.document.getElementbyid("vehicleYearOfManufactureList"). As per the comment I made below, it's a "run-time 424: object" required error

Comment: I've tried what @Bond has suggested below (adding a loop while IE.Busy) as well as many other things. I've watched some videos that do a very similar thing and the code is so simple. I've tried modifying their code for my own objective but I'm not succeeding at all. I just keep getting run-time errors or the fact that the object does not support some property etc. This is fairly depressing for something that looks so simple in other people's code - I'm really, really hoping someone can run my code and see what's going on with that last line intended to select value 2012 in the dropdown

Comment: I tried your code above and it works, but you need to wait after `e.Click`. To test, throw a `MsgBox` after `e.Click` and wait a few seconds before clicking it. Then see if the rest of your code runs properly. If so, go back and replace the `MsgBox` with a short wait period.

Comment: WOW! How exciting! It worked when I put in the message box. @Bond thank you very, very much. I now see what you meant by adding a delay!

Comment: Good luck, man. You got this.

Comment: Cheers :) - so happy about this I've missed lunch at work!

Comment: @Bond I'm stunned. My code up until this point was working well. Even when I checked this morning it was working. I've edited my code in my original question to show what had been working since yesterday. What I then noticed was that at some point, when the code clicked on the link on the original IE page, it opened the link in a new window. Yesterday and this morning it was merely opening the new link in the same window. I'm not sure if that's the reason why I get run-time error '424: Object required'. I've tried playing with internet options for tab and pop up displays but to no avail.

Comment: I noticed that as well when I was testing. You may want to just try navigating to the URL represented by the button/link on the first page instead of clicking it, which seems to open it in a popup window. So, instead of `e.Click` above, try `ie.navigate e.href`.

Comment: Oh YES! Thanks Bond! Wonderful - it's amazing how a solution can wipe away the pain of hours of prior disbelief and Googling! I also noticed something really sneaky - that href in the source code seems to almost be concealed. Only when I hovered over it with my mouse did I see what the actual link was in order to correctly navigate to this page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a few ways. If you know the index of the item, you can set it directly using the `<select>` element's `SelectedIndex` property. In your case, `"2012"` is the 4th item in the dropdown:

```
Set e = IE.document.getElementbyid("vehicleYearOfManufactureList")
e.SelectedIndex = 4
```

Alternatively, you can iterate all of the `<option>` elements in the dropdown to find the value you're looking for, then set its `Selected` property to `True`:

```
Set e = IE.document.getElementbyid("vehicleYearOfManufactureList")

Dim o
For Each o In e.Options
    If o.Value = "2012" Then
        o.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Bond - I run into another issue when I place the first two lines of code you suggested in my code. It says: "Run-time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is not available". Is that because it's trying to read the landing page as though it were the page that was opened when the code clicks on the link on the landing page? After my  last "Loop Until IE.readystate = 4" all I did was Dim b As Object. And then I copied your two lines, replacing "e" with "b". And that produces that run-time error

Comment: You may want to loop while `IE.Busy` as well and/or add some delay just to see if it's a page-loading issue.